# How i set a default value using switch input type in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the switch input type method for user to select the gender field, either male or female.

But now i want to set the default value to be 'female'. how i can set this scenario.here is my code.

On "creating a field" side:

```
{ 
  id: "gender", 
  name: "Gender",
  type: "boolean",
  itype: "switch_", 
  required: false, 
  opts: ["Male", "Female"] 
}
```

on the "switch input" side:

```
getValue: function() {
    return this.sw.value;
},
setValue: function(value) {
    this.sw.value = value;
},
```

I'm new to this. Please make your suggestions about my code.

Comment: Next time you format your question yourself. - You might want to add an explanation what a "switch input" is.

Comment: What library do you use? It doesn't look like anything I know about.